# How to update data by order of sequence in each subgroup in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a few tables that when joined will result into this example data representation.

| Group | Subgroup | Line ID | Target Field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | null |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | null |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | null |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | null |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 11 | null |
| 2 | 4 | 12 | null |
| 2 | 5 | 9 | null |
| 2 | 5 | 10 | null |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 | 4 |

Group field is the main group of data. Subgroup is, well, a sub group in the main group. Line ID is an autoincrement unique id field for each record. Now comes the Target Field where it only has value on the records in the last Subgroup of each Group. Also, Target Field is not autoincrement. Each Group will only have 3 Subgroups. Each Subgroup may have any number of lines. Every subgroup has the same number of records in each group.

I am looking for an update query that will update Target Field of each record that is null to be the same value as the record in the same order in each subgroup for each group. It is kind of confusing. I am trying to make it less confusing. So, here is what the result should be -- the expected output.

| Group | Subgroup | Line ID | Target Field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 11 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 12 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 9 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 10 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 | 4 |

How to craft such query?

Comment: To set all the value the same to match the last value in the sub ground is not a big deal. But if the values of the last sub-group are 1,2, for us to write a repeating sequence is only going to work if the size of each sub-group is the same. If sub group 1 has 3 records, what would be the 3rd value?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller LineID 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 are in the same Group 2. So, you can ignore other groups (in this case you can ignore Group 1). Now, there are 3 subgroups 4, 5, 6 in this Group. Only the last subgroup has the Target Value in each line, which is subgroup 6 in line 7 and 8. Line 7 and 8 thus contain the value I need to update to all other lines by that order. So, the value of the first line (LineID 7) of subgroup 6 will be updated to the first line in each subgroup, which are Subgroup 4/LineID 11 and Subgroup 5/LineID 9. So, LineID 11 and 9 will be updated with the value 3.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I forgot to mention that specific condition. It is assumed that every subgroup has the same number of records in each group.

Comment: I can see it, but to write a query that works with exactly 2 lines is better done in a stored procedure or in application logic, not as a _query_. It the specific condition always 2, or is it always going to have the same number of elements?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Each Group will only have 3 Subgroups. Each Subgroup may have any number of lines.

Comment: But are the number of lines within each sub-group for the main group always the same? Could subgroup 5 have 3 lines while the others have 2 in this recordset, if so, what is the value for the 3rd line?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller That case will never happen. It is agreed upon that a Group will only have 3 Subgroups -- and here's your answer -- each Subgroup in this Group will always have the same number of records. For example, Group 2 (from this question) has 3 Subgroups (4, 5, 6) and each Subgroup contains 2 records. The subgroups 4, 5, 6 will always contain 2 lines each. However, the number of lines in each subgroup may differ for other Group. That means Subgroups in Group 3 (imagined data) may contain any number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While this can be achieved, I do not recommend this as a SQL query expression at all. Logic like this is *application logic* and as such should be in your business layer or expressed as a stored procedure, not as a simple update statement.

The trick is to join back onto the corresponding sub-group by correlating the sequence of the rows, we do this by first appending a `ROW_NUMBER` into the initial dataset and then using filtered self joins to find the missing `Target Field` values.

- **NOTE:** This query is highly reliant on the following specific conditions stated by OP:

  - The sequence of values is described by the *"last Subgroup of each Group".*
  - *"Every subgroup has the same number of records in each group"*
  - for the statement *"same order in each subgroup for each group"*, I have used the `Line ID` in ascending order to determine the sequence order to apply.

db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tH3xPXKVHG7WTus6he9gJ7/0

```
WITH OrderedLines as
(
  SELECT
  "Group", "Subgroup", "Line ID"
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Group", "Subgroup" ORDER BY "Line ID") as "RN"
  , MAX("Subgroup") OVER (PARTITION BY "Group") as "MaxGroup"
  , "Target Field"
  FROM "Lines"
)
SELECT
  o."Group", o."Subgroup", o."Line ID", lkp."Target Field"
FROM OrderedLines o
INNER JOIN OrderedLines lkp ON 
    o."Group" = lkp."Group" 
    AND o."MaxGroup" = lkp."Subgroup" 
    AND o."RN" = lkp."RN"
WHERE o."Target Field" IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT "Group", "Subgroup", "Line ID", "Target Field"
FROM OrderedLines
WHERE "Target Field" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "Group", "Subgroup", "Line ID"
```

Specifically to `UPDATE` the source table based on this query, you can use this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tH3xPXKVHG7WTus6he9gJ7/3

```
WITH OrderedLines as
(
  SELECT
  "Group", "Subgroup", "Line ID"
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Group", "Subgroup" ORDER BY "Line ID") as "RN"
  , MAX("Subgroup") OVER (PARTITION BY "Group") as "MaxGroup"
  , "Target Field"
  FROM "Lines"
),
UpdatedTargets as
(
  SELECT
    o."Group", o."Subgroup", o."Line ID", lkp."Target Field"
  FROM OrderedLines o
  INNER JOIN OrderedLines lkp ON 
      o."Group" = lkp."Group" 
      AND o."MaxGroup" = lkp."Subgroup" 
      AND o."RN" = lkp."RN"
  WHERE o."Target Field" IS NULL
)
UPDATE "Lines" tgt
SET "Target Field" = src."Target Field"
FROM UpdatedTargets src
WHERE tgt."Line ID" = src."Line ID";
```